# Missing of hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-[0-9.]*.jar in hadoop1.2.1

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I have installed Hadoop 1.2.1 on a three node cluster. while installing Oozie, When i try to generate a war file for the web console, I get this error.

```
hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-[0-9.]*.jar' not found in '/home/hduser/hadoop'
```

I believe the version of Hadoop that I am using doesn't have this jar file(don't know where to find them). So can anyone please tell me how to create a war file and enable the web console. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. You have 2 options :

**1.** Download individual jars and put them inside your hadoop1.2.1 directory and generate the war file.

**2.** Download Hadoop 2.x and use it while creating the war file and once it has been built continue using your hadoop1.2.1.

> **For example :** oozie-3.3.2  bin/oozie-setup.sh prepare-war -hadoop
>   hadoop-1.1.2 ~/hadoop-eco/hadoop-2.2.0 -extjs
>   ~/hadoop-eco/oozie/oozie-3.3.2/webapp/src/main/webapp/ext-2.2

Here I have built Oozie-3.3.2 to use it with hadoop-1.1.2 but using hadoop-2.2.0

HTH

Comment: thanks, i have created the war file by building the jar files of hadoop and extjs separately (i.e) first added the hadoop 1.2.1 jar files into the war and built the war file with the extjs. Now it works.